# Android youtube API play two or more Youtube players in one main activity

Tags: java, android, json, youtube, android-youtube-api

Using the Android Youtube api i want to play two videos in my app  main activity without using fragment we have the same problem with this [Multiple Youtube players in one activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291059/multiple-youtube-players-in-one-activity) but has no acceptable answers yet please help us.

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/video1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/video2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

```
MainActivity.java

    package com.apps.you;
    import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ((YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.video1)).initialize("AIzaSyBmb9Yqu9vEBXjNOrBmZZ__6s12RH5RSv0", new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider1, YouTubePlayer player1, boolean restored1) {
            if (!restored1) {
            player1.cueVideo("Daa38ruXHxE");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider1, YouTubeInitializationResult result1) {
        }
    });

    ((YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.video2)).initialize("AIzaSyBmb9Yqu9vEBXjNOrBmZZ__6s12RH5RSv0", new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

        public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean restored) {

            if (!restored) {
        player.loadVideo("ctQAPiojDKE");
            }
        }


        public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
        }
    });
}
}
```

the problem with this is only one video was playing at the end , video1 initialization was overrriden by the video2 initialization they call the same

```
  .initialize(new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener(){});
```

by this:

```
((YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.video1)).initialize(new
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener(){});

((YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.video2)).initialize(new
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener(){});
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Eliran Tutia  as far as I remember I can only play and initialize one video at a time per activity  even using fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe trivial answer. But is for your use-case acceptable to call init of second youtube player from success callback of the first one? Have you tried it? It should be a reasonable workaround.

But there might be a catch that is extending YouTubeBaseActivity I looked up documentation, and it looks like there can be only one YouTubeView per activity because of binding between them.

So I can offer another advice, use YouTubePlayerFragment or SupportYouTubePlayerFragment instead. It should have its own lifecycle (not tested).

Comment: tried to call init of second youtube player from success callback of the first one. doesn't work due to limitation =(

Comment: using youtubeplayerfragments don't allow it to work either

Answer (score 0):

To achieve two or more youtube players at one activity you need to use [YouTubeThumbnailView](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeThumbnailView)(It is an ImageView) to show a list of preview images. When the user touch the thumb, you redirect to full screen video player.

[Check out this project.](https://github.com/Glurt/EdenYouTube.git)